# Question draft: I have been denied a visa several times in a row. How does one deal with such serial refusals?

Tags: discussion

Over the course of time here on TSE, I have observed individuals whose pattern of visa applications best described as '[serial refusals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/serial-refusals)'...

> *serial refusals* - Two or more consecutive visa refusals issued by the same regime to the same person. Commonly for the same, or nearly the same, reasons. In some visa regimes Serial refusals can have a cumulative effect wherein the applicant's credibility is increasingly eroded, especially when the application pattern suggests a secondary agenda.

A common thread appears to be the need to visit the destination country (especially Schengen, the USA, or the UK) with a special sense of urgency. Also common in these cases are the following types of questions...

1. Should I just reapply once again? What are my chances?
2. What can I do to improve my odds in the future?
3. Can I somehow address the previous refusals to avoid them being a burden on all future applications?

   4. How can I break the pattern?

Comment: I take it that, following your earlier question, you are asking for 'answers' that might quailfy as a canonical question. But it is not clear, especially to those who have not seen the earlier..